# Why AJAX request doesn't pass is_ajax_request() codeigniter's condition?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On form submit, I make an AJAX request with jquery $.ajax:

```
$('form.sendMessage').off('submit').on('submit', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $('form.sendMessage');
        
            if (form.valid(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + <?=$moduleUrl?> + '/sendMessage',
                    data: form.serialize();
                    type: 'POST',
                    beforeSubmit: function () {
                        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to send this message?')) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        toastr.success("Message sent", "Success");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        toastr.error(response, "Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        )
        });
```

In controller, to the sendMessage method where the request is made, I have a condition which, if passed continues to the sendingMessage method:

```
public function sendMessage()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post(null, true);

        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request() && !empty($post)) {
            try {
                $this->sendingMessage($post);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->output->set_status_header('401')
                    ->set_output($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private function sendingMessage($post)
    {
        if (!empty($post) && (int)$post['device'] > 0 && isset($post['message'])) {
            $this->load->model('protectee/device_messages');
            // save in db
            $data = [
                'device_id' => $post['device'],
                'user_id'   => $_SESSION['UserID'],
                'message'   => $post['message'],
                'date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ];
            $messageId = $this->device_messages->insertMessage($data);

            if ($messageId > 0) {
                $this->insertCommand($post['device'], 'MSG', '<br>' . $post['message']);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Message could not be send! Please try again..');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('An error occured! Please try again..');
        }
    }
```

When I submit the form, it goes to a blank page and the URL is changed to .../sendMessage.
So, I figure, it does not fulfill the condition of being an ajax_request `if ($this-\>input-\>is_ajax_request() && !empty($post)`.

Comment: This is not related to my question, but is still about the code above. Is $this->input->is_ajax_request() && !empty($post) enough as a backend validation, or I still need to add if (! $this->validate...? And if I do, I suppose I must do it in sendMessage method...right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You submit handler is not set, this is because there is a syntax error in it.
The url parameter has the issue, the php output is not a string.

```
url: base_url + '<?=$moduleUrl?>' + '/sendMessage',
```